# Can I add collision detection to symbols used in other symbols?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, collision-detection, flashdevelop

I'm trying to make a 2-D platformer using Adobe Flash CS6, Actionscript 3.0 and FlashDevelop, and I've been stuck in a rut for what seems like forever trying to figure out how to add collision detection to my player and walls.
I have a Level1 symbol that is comprised of multiple Surface symbols (which is just a grey rectangle), and was wondering if there was a way to add collision detection to the Surface symbol and have it updated across all occurrences of it in my Level1 symbol, instead of adding collision events for every Surface symbol in my Level1 symbol individually.
I have a feeling I'm going about it all wrong.

Answer (score 0):

No it's fine. You're not thinking something wrong.

You can add an ENTER_FRAME event listener to your Level1 instance then you can control collision events from itself. (I'm using similar way for my game too)

You just need an Array of your rectangles in your Level1 symbol. Create an array variable that holds list of rectangles.

private var rectanglesList:Array = new Array();

Then just push Rectangles into that array when rectangles added to stage.

Collision check is easy too..
You can use "for each" to check collision in your Level1's "enter_frame" function like that

```
for each (var r:Rectangle in this.rectanglesList)
{
 if (r collides with player)
 {
  //what you wanna do
 }
}
```